# How do I fix a 'Missing enviornment variable' in Sanity?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sanity

I have tried everything to fix it but still getting the error

[image]

> Uncaught error: Missing environment variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET
> http://localhost:3333/static/sanity-5377bc10.js:4605:43956
> Error: Missing environment variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET
>     at Wke (http://localhost:3333/static/sanity-5377bc10.js:4605:43956)
>     at http://localhost:3333/static/sanity-5377bc10.js:4605:43720

Comment: Where/when are you getting this error? Are you installing Sanity? Using it? Running some code somewhere? See [mcve] for more info on how you can improve your question so it is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: no error in the code its was after I ran sanity start and clicked the server link

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `SANITY_STUDIO_` prefix, *not* the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix.

[See Sanity.io documentation on env variables](https://www.sanity.io/docs/environment-variables)

To fix your error:

1. Replace mentions of `NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET` with `SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET`
2. Ensure `SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET` is set with correct project ID in your environment

Answer (score 0):

literally and I think this is silly but it worked for me. Change the naming convention in your .env or .env.local file (also dont forget to change everything referencing it also aswell) and also move the env file to the sanity root folder if you're still having issues

before
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID="your ID"
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET="your dataset"

after
SANITY_STUDIO_PROJECT_ID="your ID"
SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET="your Dataset"

this is due to the changes in the way the sanity environment has changed to look for env variables. but when you install sanity it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34702063)